# What is the notation $f¢(x)$ stands for in context of derivatives?

Tags: derivatives, notation

Consider the remark given [here](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/lemh106.pdf#page=8) in the chapter 6 named `APPLICATION OF DERIVATIVES` from [NCERT](https://ncert.nic.in/) class 12 book

> **There is a more generalised theorem**, which states that if $\mathbf{f¢(x) > 0}$
> for $x$ in an interval excluding the end points and $f$ is continuous
> in the interval, then $f$ is increasing. Similarly, if $\mathbf{f¢(x) < 0}$ for
> $x$ in an interval excluding the end points and $f$ is continuous in
> the interval, then $f$ is decreasing.

I am facing two issues in understanding it,

1. What is the notation $f¢(x)$? Is it $f'(x)$?
2. How is it a generalisation of the following theorem as told? (I can see no difference in both, if 1 is true)

> Let $f$ be continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on the open
> interval $(a,b)$. Then
>
> (a) $f$ is increasing in $[a,b]$ if $f ′(x) > 0$ for each $x \in (a,
>  b)$
>
> (b) $f$ is decreasing in $[a,b]$ if $f ′(x) < 0$ for each $x \in (a,
>  b)$
>
> (c) $f$ is a constant function in $[a,b]$ if $f ′(x) = 0$ for each $x
>  \in (a, b)$

Comment: Seems like a rendering issue.

Comment: What is the name/author of the book you linked to?

Comment: @DavidSheard It is an [NCERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Council_of_Educational_Research_and_Training) book.

Comment: I've never come across this notation, either it is a typo/rendering issue as suggested above, or it's likely to be some obscure/non-standard notation, which will therefore be defined in an earlier chapter or glossary

Comment: Very odd... apparently neither $\cent$ nor $\cents$ in TeX/MathJax makes the "cent" sign... with or without dollar signs around them...

Comment: @paulgarrett  I looked at the book. It's definitely not $\LaTeX$-ed.

Comment: It's obviously a rendering issue, since the remark immediately follows a passage about the derivative $f'(x)$.

Comment: @Randall, now that I think about it, sometimes weird typos are deliberately inserted for later evidence of copyright violations... but, still, ...

Comment: @Randall: I am sure you are right that there is a rendering problem, but if you read it as $f'(x)$, it just seems to restate the preceding theorem rather than generalise it (I think this is the OP's point 2). A mystery to me.

Comment: I take the "more general" part to mean that they may be applying it to intervals different from $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Randall: you may well be right: if it means $f'(x)$, they could just be generalising to open and half-open intervals.

Comment: As an aside, NCERT is in India.

Answer (score 3):

It is a misprinted character.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8hXbvn1ab-BaXM0YjVhc285Z28/view?resourcekey=0-QLQBstamNZCN-LyLg9dXGQ

You can find the intention in this version/edition above.
[image]